# What is the linearity-like property $f(x, a + b) = f(f(x, a), b)$ called?

Tags: functions, terminology, linear-approximation

A function $f : S \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S$ could have the property

$$ f(x, a + b) = f(f(x, a), b) .$$

For example, with $S = \mathbb{R}$ it is true of $f(x, a) = x + ka$ and $f(x, a) = xk^a$.

**What can this property be called?** It seems like it should be something “… linear …” but I don't know exactly what.

---

The particular case I am immediately interested in describing using this term is that the property *almost* holds for the function
$$f(x, a) = (1 + ka)x$$
in which case we find that
$$
\begin{align}
f(f(x, a), b)
&= (1 + kb)(1 + ka)x \\
&= (ka + kb + k^2ab + 1)x \\
&= (1 + k(a + b + kab))x \\
&= f(x, a + b + kab)
\end{align}
$$
and we can then consider whether the difference $kab$ is small enough that $f(f(x, a), b)$ is a suitable approximation for $f(x, a + b)$ in the particular application.

Comment: I doubt this has a name, but $1+ka$ reminded me of the series for $(e^k)^a$, and this property can be evidenced by Hyperoperations. Examples: $(a+b)+x=b+(a+x)$, $7^{a+b}x=7^b\left(7^a x\right)$, and with tetration: $\left(^{a+b}5\right)^{x}=\left(^{b}5\right)\wedge\left(\left(^{a}5\right)^{x}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

For each $t\in \mathbb R$, you obtain a map $f_t= f(-,t): S\longrightarrow S$. Your condition means that

$$f_{s+t}(p) = f(p,s+t) = f(f(p,t),s) = f_t(f_s(p))$$

that is $f_{t+s}=f_t\circ f_s$. Observe, moreover, that in your examples we also have that $f_0$ is the identity, so by the above $f_t$ is bijective with inverse $f_{-t}$.

This means there is a map $\mathbb R\longrightarrow \operatorname{Homeo}(S)$ (where $\operatorname{Homeo}$ stands for the group of homeomorphisms of the space $S$) that is a morphism of groups. Such maps are termed *one parameter groups*, and arise naturally when considering flows of vector fields on manifolds.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting and I particularly appreciate your having gotten it into the form of a function composition. I feel like the description you propose is too abstract to be _more useful than not trying to name the property_ (for myself and the people that might read what I write), though, so I hope for another answer with a different angle too.